# Window Manufacturer - Anyone recognize this window?

Tags: basement, windows

I am trying to find the manufacturer of this window or anyone that sells it.  I'm in the northeast (NY).  It's set in a poured concrete foundation.  The glass only has "strips" on either side (which is unusual), so the top/bottom actually fit into the tracks in the window frame.  Need to find the "strips" if possible, as the previous owner of my home broke the windows when they were locked-out and threw out the strips instead of trying to replace the glass.  I tried Home Depot, Lowe's...asked several concrete companies, construction supply stores, etc. with no luck.  [window/glass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM1eV.jpg)[image: frame with clips that window locks into]

Comment: These types of questions are really hard to answer.  This looks like a fairly old door, and it may be impossible to find parts.  The best I can suggest is to find a good glazier and have them come out to take a look.  But seriously consider replacing the entire door and frame.  You might even save enough on heating over a couple of years to pay for it.

Comment: Square head hardware screws are relatively modern

Answer (score 2):

You may very well be looking till doomsday trying to find repair parts for old broken windows. And even if you do find parts you will still be left with some thirty five or forty year old window.

You will likely be better off looking at ripping out the remnants of the window and replacing it with something new that is double or triple glazed in an all vinyl frame that will provide much better energy efficiency than the old unit ever did.

Measure carefully and study replacement type window styles that will install easily. Most windows like this are custom made to size.